# Why flagging duplicate answers is waste of time?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-answers

Today I was flag this first answer as a *duplicate answer* with 2 and 3.

1. [drawInRect error: CGContextSetFont: invalid context 0x0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261375/drawinrect-error-cgcontextsetfont-invalid-context-0x0/15654689#15654689)
2. [drawRect and dispatch context error 0x0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576270/drawrect-and-dispatch-context-error-0x0/15648889#15648889)
3. [iOS : Core Text - loosing context when drawing image inside a block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927942/ios-core-text-loosing-context-when-drawing-image-inside-a-block/15648829#15648829)

This flag was declined and moderator noted:

> Do you know that you're wasting your time?
>
> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYZ0j.png]

Did I something wrong here? Flagging duplicate answers is wrong?

**EDIT**: I think I owe you an apology. As *Bill the Lizard* [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173809/158761), moderators warned me before but since I didn't read their message, looks like I continue to wrong flag this kind of answers. I'm deeply sorry for that!

*The moderator message could be nicer?* Yeah.. But hey :) Things can happen...

Comment: How long can the decline reason be? The moderator could have be a little more informative.

Comment: I think the decline message shouldn't be a rhetorical question...

Comment: The real question here is which moderator felt the need to be a dick to somebody trying to help the site by daring to use flags.

Comment: @meagar: Did you know he's wasting his time ? :)

Comment: @meagar: As it turns out, the mod had already tried to tell the OP in nicer terms time was being wasted. Because the OP was wasting his time. Really.

Comment: Absolutely no apology needed.  Don't sweat it.  I probably should have just dropped a mod message, would have saved this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> The real question here is which moderator felt the need to be a dick to somebody trying to help the site by daring to use flags. – meagar 18 mins ago
>
> @meagar This is exactly what I think also.. – Soner Gönül 16 mins ago

I don't mean to condone the snarky tone of the decline message, but you have been told before, more politely, that you don't need to flag these posts.

[image: declined message]

These are fairly low priority flags, and they don't need to be bumped up the queue by having people piggy-back off the automatic Community flag to raise their flag weight.  Go ahead and flag the question if it's also a duplicate.  That's a much better use of our time and yours.

Comment: So why not suspend the user from flagging for a while?

Comment: @0A0D That's what declining a flag does. If you get enough of your flags declined, they become meaningless in the system.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Sounds like the flagging system needs some tweaking to detect this

Comment: @0A0D I don't think this is nearly bad enough behavior to warrant a ban on anything.  I'd rather just ask the person to stop and hope they see the declined flags.  If I'd seen the many later flags by the same user for the same thing, I'd have probably sent him a private mod message instead of continuing to decline flags.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I am not a mod obviously so I can't see the tools you guys see, but is it really that annoying to see those flags? It almost seems futile to even respond at all (meaning custom message).

Comment: @0A0D Only if there are a lot of them pushing other flags further down the queue.  Just one of two are easily ignored (and usually dismissed as helpful, because that's just way less effort).

Comment: @BilltheLizard I accept your answer because you pointed to me the right direction before but I might ignore it. I edit the question also. Thanks and sorry.. again.

Comment: @SonerGönül Thanks, and it's not that big a deal. Like we said, it's not really *bad* behavior at all, it's just not necessary.

Answer (score 18):

Flagging duplicate answers is a waste, for the following reason:

- If the OP copies his own answer, then the system warns us automatically, every time they do it (which leads to an interesting flag queue if they do it a couple times)

However,

- If the OP copies someone elses answer, then that's something that the system doesn't alert us to.

If you see someone plagarizing, please let us know through a flag. If someone is just copying and pasting their answers, let it go (though that may be an indication that the questions are duplicates, which are worthy of close votes or flags as appropriate).

Sometimes moderator messages are ... less than helpful.  We see a lot of flags in a day, and there are times that we don't take the time to either

1. decline with a link to a meta post
2. decline with a long winded explanation

Usually, however, we do.  When we don't, it's probably because one of the following reasons:

1. We've seen way too many mod flags that day
2. The user is consistently flagging for the same thing in an effort to up their flag weight (usually by doing an SEDE search for 'best' and then flagging 4 year old questions as not constructive, and 4 year old link only answers as 'not an answer')
3. The user is (for whatever reason) fixated on another user. We see this more than we probably should.
4. We get *in a mood*. This happens. We're human. Should it? Probably not -- but clearing hundreds of flags every day will lead a person to snark every once in a while.

I'm sorry you had a less than helpful mod message.

Answer (score 17):

Sorry to be blunt, but I've tried to contact you about this (without using the **babies-are-being-eaten-by-dingos!** mod message facilities) without success.

As others have stated, we *already* get notified that a user has reposted the same answer on multiple questions.  Therefore, whatever you are doing to search these out and flag them is a *complete waste of your time*.

This isn't "wrong", per se.  We would appreciate it *if it wasn't already automatically handled by the system.*  This is just a waste of your time, something you should have more of.

Comment: Next time a *"No need to flag. This is reported to us automatically"* message might be more clear.

Comment: @Bart: [You mean like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bVmV4.png)

Comment: Hmm, you're way more awesome than I imagined....Can't be Won't...you're Will, aren't you?

Comment: @Bart: Right on both accounts.

Answer (score 16):

Duplicate answers by the same author are perhaps indicative of *duplicate questions*, but by themselves they are fine. Close the *question* instead.

Since those 3 answers are exact dupes, you are indeed wasting your time; exactly duplicate answers are *automatically* flagged already by the system, so moderators can investigate and find dupe questions. Granted, the flag feedback could have been a little less terse on that, but perhaps the mods already tried to tell you your efforts were in vain?

If you do find duplicate answers that are by **different** authors, then that could indicate plagiarism and gaming by one of the authors. *Do* flag *those*.

Answer (score 13):

Our moderation team works very hard, each active moderator on the site spends an average of at least an hour a day, if not more, looking at the *worst* content that we have to offer. At an average of almost 2,000 flags per day, we ask a lot of these folks - and they consistently give us more than we ask for when it comes to their time and patience.

You were, as others pointed out, notified that the type of flag you were raising was not necessary - the system automatically raises those flags. It's likely that you didn't notice the first flag rejected, and continued to keep flagging.

Moderators declining a flag have a very limited number of characters to enter if they wish to give a custom response, and he *was* trying to point out to you that you were wasting your time by raising the flags. While it came off somewhat snarky, he *was* trying to be helpful. He's also human. Comments, chat and possibly a system sent moderator message might have been a better way to reach you, but hindsight is always crystal clear.

To answer your question again, directly - while we appreciate your time, the system automatically flags duplicate content by the same author, so no, you don't need to flag it.

If you see duplicate content by *different* authors **flag it**, we're probably dealing with plagiarism which is a very serious issue, one the moderator you interacted with is very good at investigating and ultimately handling :) The system really can't, therefore doesn't automatically raise flags for this.

Comment: And the system currently does NOT flag identical (or very similar) answers by different users (which would burn crazy cycles), so looking out for plagiarized answers is a much more productive and helpful way to spend your leisure flagging time.

Comment: @Won't Edited a bit to make that clearer, definitely worth it.

Comment: flagging guidance in two last paragraphs looks worth copying to **[duplicate-answers tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/duplicate-answers/info)** for easier reference in further discussions

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate **answers** are not in themselves a bad thing. The same answer may apply to different questions. If the **questions** are duplicates, however, feel free to flag them or vote to close.

It is even allowed to copy someone else's answer as long as you attribute it to the original author (see the [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license).