# Wouldn't be great if we don't see duplicate answers by same user?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, 10k-tools, duplicate-answers

We discussed on this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173801/why-flagging-duplicate-answers-is-waste-of-time) and it is clearly flagging dublicate answers by same user is waste of time. I did wrong flags because of this.

Because at the begining, I just look at [duplicate answers](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?subtype=duplicateanswer) and I see duplicate answers (don't care too much by the same user or not) and *I think it is ok to flag those answers*. **But it wasn't.** I think a lot of people might felt the same situation..

Duplicate answers by same user automaticly notified to the moderators by the system. So, wouldn't be great if we don't see them in [flagging part](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?subtype=duplicateanswer)?

Or at least a warning message like;

> *You shouldn't flag this answers because duplicate answers by the same
>   user is automaticly notified to moderators by the system.*

Comment: Can you edit your question and tag so it's clear this pertains to the moderator queue?  And some background for those of us of < 10k.

Comment: I assume your topic is duplicate answers to the same question (by the same user), and the fact that the system is able to automatically flag these for moderator attention.  Would you explain a bit more what it means not to "see them in flagging part"?

Comment: @hardmath I know that those answers notified by the system as I wrote in my answer. My point is, finding a way to prevent flagging those type of answers because it is wasting time..

Comment: @SonerGönül:  I was mislead by the title and thought your suggestion was to prevent seeing these duplicate answers by the same user (versus as you now describe, to prevent flagging them).

Comment: @hardmath: The topic is duplicate answers to **different** questions by the same user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flag is there to harness the community's power on the case. What you as a user can do:

- Comment - Instruct the user to not just duplicate his answer, but to actually write an answer for any specific question.
- Close one question as a duplicate of the other - Often, if the same answer applies to two questions, one is duplicate of the other.
- Do nothing (or flag as invalid flag) - Sometimes, we just don't care. Posting the same answer twice isn't a crime, especially if the same answer perfectly applies to both questions. Sometimes, we just don't need to do anything.

Yes, moderators can handle the flag. But the whole point of the 10k tools is to overload some of the work to the community.

Comment: Yeah, commenting would be ok but  when people try to flag them, at leaset a warning message can be great for informing them..

Comment: @SonerGönül: A moderator can clear all the flags on a post with one step ([I know](http://anime.stackexchange.com/users/27/madara-uchiha)). So why do we care if there are 1 or 10 flags on a single post?

Comment: _Because people do wrong flagging by this_. That's why we should care.. It is not about clear all flags, it is about preventing wrong flagging by the users..

Comment: @SonerGönül: I don't understand why flagging is the wrong action. If the answer *is* a duplicate, and it *shouldn't* be there, flagging is a normal course of action. Sure, there's deleting it (which isn't possible of both answers are upvoted), and commenting. But flagging for a moderator is a valid action. Please explain **why** is it wrong.

Comment: One more option: Flag one (or more of the duplicates) for moderator attention, as potential spam.

Comment: @ypercube: That depends if it's spam, and that applies to all other posts as well.

Comment: I know, that's why i said "potential". The moderators can examine the situation, search the answers, chat with the answerer and probably have more options to follow than the rest of us.